# Mysql query giving problems with JSON.parse in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am developing a small app for learning purposes.

For this app, I have a Mysql database where each row is a "task". Each task has one "status" field, among others like id_task. When I click a button, an AJAX call sends a request to a PHP file where status is updated and results retrieved.

The possible values of the status are NULL (default) "DONE" and "REMOVE".

I use it to create a list with all the tasks, and depending on the status, text will appear green colored ("DONE"), default black color ("NULL") or won´t appear ("REMOVE").

Yeah, I could simply delete the "removed" tasks but I prefer to maintain them on the database in case I want the user to be able to recover them

Everything works fine when the php function I created to do that has this sql query:

```
public function retrieveDataByID($p_id_task)
{
    $result="";

    $arraySubjects=array();

    $this->openConnection();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tareas where id_task=".$p_id_task;

    $result=mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);

    if($result !=null)
    {

       while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
           $arrayEditedSubjects[]=$fila;

       }



    }else{
        //echo "no results";
    }


    $this->closeConnection();

    return $arrayEditedSubjects;

}
```

But when I want to filter the query to make the rows with status "REMOVE" don´t appear, the list is not generated and AJAX call throws this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON    data
```

I don´t know what could be going wrong. Here is the code with the problematic query:

```
public function retrieveDataByID($p_id_task)
{
    $result="";

    $arraySubjects=array();

    $this->openConnection();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tareas where (id_task=".$p_id_task.") AND (status <> 'REMOVE')";


    $result=mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);

    if($result !=null)
    {

       while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
           $arrayEditedSubjects[]=$fila;

       }



    }else{
        //echo "no results";
    }


    $this->closeConnection();

    return $arrayEditedSubjects;

}
```

Here is the **AJAX call** which throws the error, in case it may help you:

```
$.ajax({

    method:"post",
    data:{'day_and_month':cellIDValue},
    url:"assets/php/retrieve.php",


    success:function(result){

        let parsedResult=JSON.parse(result);

        buildList("#subjectDiv",parsedResult);


   },
   error: function(xhr){
       alert(xhr.status);
   }

});
```

And here is the **retrieve.php** file called on the AJAX function

```
<?php

    require_once('models/Connect.php');/*this is where the retrieveDataByID  function is defined*/

    $arrayJSONresults=array();
    $objConexion=new Connection;

    $arrayJSONresults= $objConexion->retrieveData($_POST['day_and_month']);

    echo json_encode($arrayJSONresults);



?>
```

Comment: `echo "no results";` is not json and if that gets output before the json then whole response is invalid. A json response must only contain one echo

Comment: try `console.log(result);` to view the response in your browser console for debugging purposes

Comment: @charlietfl fixed that but I still have the same problem.

Comment: See what is actually sent from server by inspecting the request in browser dev tools network. You can look at response body there and copy it to a json validator and/or get clues why it fails

Comment: Off topic: `$arrayJSONresults="";`  shouldn't you be defining `$arrayJSONresults = array();` or `$arrayJSONresults = [];` instead for better readablity.  As you did with your `$arraySubjects=array();`

Comment: @RaymondNijland True, I did not notice it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it doing the following query:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tareas where (id_task=".$p_id_task.") AND ((status IS NULL) OR (status <> 'REMOVE'))";
```

As the default status is NULL, I had to evaluate first if the status IS NULL (in other case, I have read SQL engine can´t evaluate it right).

Then, if it IS NULL, or different from "REMOVE" (that means, NULL or "DONE") it will be shown in the list.

Maybe I do that default status is something different of NULL to avoid that, but I learned something new now.